# Amount for transaction on Blockchain not the same as what I sent

Tags: transactions, wallet

Thank you in advance for taking the time to answer my question!

I am new to Bitcoin, and although not a computer programmer I have recently done a deep dive into learning how it works, and am admittedly amazed with all its nuances -- the 4-year halvings, 21 million hard cap, difficulty level adjustment, hash rates, sha-256, etc. and the incentive structure is very well designed for sound money in my humble opinion.

Recently for curiosity, I tried to locate one of my transactions on memepool.space and found the transaction but it was a higher amount than what I sent (including the fee). For example I sent, say, 0.0005 BTC with 0.00005 fee for total of 0.00055 BTC. However, there was another combined amount listed below this amount of, say, 0.0004 showing the total sent to be 0.00095 BTC. This was sent via a Ledger Nano S to another Ledger Nano S private wallet and within the Live Ledger software it all shows the correct amounts of 0.00055 sent and the other shows 0.0005 received.

I hope all this is making sense. My question is what exactly is happening in this transaction and why there would be a substantially higher amount sent and who's might this 0.0004 extra BTC belong to?

Any insight you could offer about what is happening with this, I would appreciate very much. Thank you!